# yeoman - switch between typescript and Javascript

Tags: knockout.js, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I'm using yeoman in an SPA application.  I'm generating components with ko:component.

My problem is that the generated files are in typescript and I want to switch it to Javascript.

How can I do it besides manually going over the output files and changing them to Javascript?